# Moving elements when changing UIView frame

Tags: objective-c, ios6, autolayout

I have few UITextView's. Every TextView changes it's sizes on focus - it grows about 50px with animation like this:

```
[UITextView animateWithDuration:.1f animations:^{
    CGRect new_frame = textView.frame;
    new_frame.size.height += height;
    textView.frame = new_frame;
}];
```

Now my problem is I need to move TextViews under the focused one 50px down (also with animation apparently). I'm wondering how to do that the simplest way. My app is iOS6 only, so I can use autolayouts. I tried and failed. I tried using struts and springs - also failed.

The only solution that comes to mind is to just move every element that 50 px down with animation. But it sounds cheap to me. Any ideas how to do it? Is it possible with autolayouts?

**EDIT**

Here are the layouts I've been trying:

[image: Vertical layout]

[image]

Here is how it looks in simulator after clicking the first TextView:

[image]

So as you can see it rather cover's next view and doesn't keep the constraint.

Comment: autolayout should definitely accomplish what your looking to do. I haven't looked into any implementation but watching the videos I know that it is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't combine frames with autolayout, that'll give you unpredictable results.

Remove the constraint from the top of the second `UITextView` to the top of its superview.

Then create an outlet for the height constraint of the `UITextView`.

Use the following code to adjust the height of the `UITextView`:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UITextView animateWithDuration:.1f animations:^{
        self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant +=50;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UITextView animateWithDuration:.1f animations:^{
        self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant -=50;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be possible pretty easily with auto layout, you'd need to set a vertical space constraint on each text view that tells it to leave x pixels between the text view above it.

here's a nice autolayout tutorial that should help explain some of the concepts, if you've not used autolayout before its a little tricky.

[Beginning Auto Layout in iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Comment: Thanks - what I tried with autolayout is to add vertical constraint between two following elements. It didn't help, I added line: ` [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
` and the only thing I see is in the debugger I get a list of constraints with suggestion to delete one since they're conflicting. I'll keep trying

Comment: can you take a screenshot of interface builder showing the constraints for the second text view?

Comment: it looks like the second text view still has a constraint to the superview, you should be able to promote that constraint to a user constraint and delete it. with that gone you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a problem for which Apple provided a solution with table views.

You can grow the height of one row in a table view and the following rows will automatically pushed down. It is also quite straight forward to animate this.