# How to arrange UIControls relatively

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have buttons, labels, etc. in a view. Some elements have no height so I want to set the required height if a button is clicked. No problems so far.
I want the following elements sliding down and arranging themselves new. I have tried a `FlowLayoutController` and `Auto Layout Constraints` but both didn't fulfill my requirements.

The only way I see is to calculate all elements and arrange them programmatically when one item is added or resized.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:

[Moving elements when changing UIView frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025034/moving-elements-when-changing-uiview-frame/16037646#16037646)

The important sentence is: Don't combine frames with autolayout, that'll give you unpredictable results.

So i set the height with an IBOutlet and `self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant`.

Now it works works great.

Comment: After all, i have decided to calculate the positions of the elements by myself. Constraints gives me really unpredictable results. And xcode add some constraints if the user constraints arent enough.  Now i use an array to hold the subviews an then i go through it and set  `subViewFrame.origin.y = preSubViewFrame.origin.y + preSubViewFrame.size.height + margin;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust a UIView's frame and make it animate as if they were sliding out/down/whatever you like. You can just use some simple animation mechanics.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
//[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
//change your view's frame (height) here
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This should do the trick for you! Good luck ;)

Comment: The point is not the animation while resizing the elements more to reposioning the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [view autolayout possibilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853), that will enable automatic layout of your views. Alternatively, you can do it yourself in the 'layoutSubviews' method.

Comment: I have the following autolayout settings:

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/96/bildschirmfoto20130418u.png/  
but when i resize the Label the View beneath the Label wont change his position  
  
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/bildschirmfoto20130418un.png/  
  
`substanceDetailLabel.frame = CGRectMake(substanceDetailLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                  substanceDetailLabel.frame.origin.y,
                                  substanceDetailLabel.frame.size.width,
                                  substanceDetailLabel.frame.size.height+100);
    [self.view layoutSubviews];`

Comment: I am not so familiar myself with the auto-layout stuff, so this is guessing: You should have a "Vertical Space" constraint between your label and each of your buttons and I don't see those in your list of constraints. And instead of 'layoutSubviews' you should call 'setNeedsLayout' on the superview.